# Easiest way to play video?

Tags: java, swing, video, jframe, codec

EDIT: If your havng my problem, please watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orMgNh0o38A

I have a `JFrame` setup for my game, I'd like to play a quick video before my game loads. How would I go about playing the video the easiest way?

The video should not include controls etc, just the video so my whole frame should be the video!

I've read other topics on this and they dont seem to help... at all D:

I'm not the best Java programmer so don't expect me to know every API and how to use them.

Comment: *"..how would I go about playing the video the easiest way?"*  Hire someone that already knows how (is always the easiest way).  For a 'less than easiest way', look to embed a Java-FX based [`MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html).  For an obsolete way, look to JMF.

Comment: I cant exactly hire someone... Im making the game for fun and hopefully to publish on steam... but I doubt ill get that far D:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing video in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277921/playing-video-in-java)

Comment: I read that and it didnt help.... I just want to display video in my JFrame with no controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VLCJ to play video, and you can use this link to add the video to jpanel which you can show on startup : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20426375

Comment: How do I install vlcj? Something about Maven? Whats that?? :O

Comment: i assume you must have figured out till now. any how you can find the latest version here for maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/3.8.0

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't use maven I just downloaded the jars and added them to my build path